# How to join two tables in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, left-join

I am new to Laravel. I am having a difficulty in joining two tables (User Table and Transaction Table). Below are codes from TransactionController.

```
public function index()
{
    $user = User::all();
    $transactions = $user->transactions;
    $transaction = array();

    foreach ($transactions as $row) {
        array_push($transaction,
        [
            'id' => $row->id,
            'name' => $row->user->name,
        ]
        );
    }

    return response() -> json ([
        'transaction' => $transaction,
    ]);
}
```

I would like to print all users' name and all transactions in the Postman. I manage to print all users' name but when I tried to join with Transaction table, I am facing an error. I already tried left join method as below:

```
$user = User::all() 
  ->select('user.id','user.name')
  ->join('transactions','transactions.id','=','user.id')
  ->get();

  foreach ($transactions as $row) {
        array_push($transaction,
        [
            'id' => $row->id,
            'name' => $row->user->name,
        ]
        );
    }

    return response() -> json ([
        'transaction' => $transaction,
    ]);
}
```

Is there any way to join two tables in laravel? Thank you.

Comment: what was the error ?

Comment: Actually I want to print all users' transactions in Postman. If I used ` $user = Auth::guard('api')->user();` it will print only certain user's transaction based on user's id

Comment: You've got quite a few issues with the code you've written.  I think it would help you most if you reviewed Laravel relationships, and collections.  You can't pull a list of transactions from a collection, you need to loop on those users to get the txns for each.  But this is all predicated by you having relationships set up correctly.

Comment: @Watercayman Does it means I need to do multiple foreach loop?

Comment: Users and Transactions are one to many.  Each user will have more than one transaction as a collection.  You can't get `user->transaction` from the collection of users, you have to loop on the `users`, then either loop on the `transaction` or pick one.  This is what I meant by needing to perhaps do a little study on relationships and collections.

Comment: @Watercayman Oh I see. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have this relationship in your User model.

```
public function transactions() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction', 'user_id');
}
```

And in your Transaction model

```
public function user() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

Now, to fetch users together with their transactions

```
$users = User::with('transactions')->get();
```

If you want to fetch transactions inline with user

```
 $data = Transaction::with('user')->get();

 $transactions = collect($data)->map(function ($transaction){
    return [
        'id' => $transaction->id,
        'name' => $transaction->user->name,
        'total' => $transaction->total,
    ];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutions. But unfortunately, I still get an error to display all users' transaction

Comment: you just want the transactions only ? not users with their transactions ?

Comment: When I try to run in Postman, it show 500Internal Server Error where it didn't print the data inside the Postman API

Comment: 500 ? now, do you have a transaction model ?

Comment: actually I want to print all users' name and transaction. In Postman, the data should show like this:                                                                                         `{
    "transaction": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Adam",
            "total": "$4.00"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Ariana",
            "total": "$12.00"
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: But 'name' is coming from 'user' table while 'id' and 'total' is coming from 'transaction' table

Comment: Yes, I have Transaction model in my Laravel project

Comment: Should be a good practice to post your models alongside your controller in order to get responses in accurate context.